# Ft python 3 library equivalent

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to translate code from python 2 to 3 and it has the following imports which do not exist in python 3:

```
import Ft
from Ft.Xml.Domlette import NonvalidatingReader
from Ft.Xml.XPath import Evaluate
```

Is there any equivalent for these imports in python 3?

Comment: I don't find `Ft` in the build-in, so they don't have a python 3 compatible version?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `Ft` is written for python2 and not ported to python3. You should use another xml library like lxml